# embedded erb in rails css files

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, background-image, erb

I am trying to style a div container and add a background image, that is an image uploaded by a user and stored in the database (adventure.image.url). I am unsure how to embed what would have been erb code in the css file.

Here is the code from the index.html.erb file:

```html
<div class="adventure_container">
      <% @adventures.each do |adventure|%>
        <div class="adventure">
          <%= link_to "#{adventure.title}", adventure_path(adventure.id), class: "adventure_title" %>
          <%= (image_tag adventure.image.url(:medium), class:'adv_img') %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS (or SCSS) code I want to add the image to as a background to:

```css
.adventure {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  // background-color: #e9e8e8;
  background-image: url()
  margin: 1%;
  // border: 1px solid purple;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline-styling like this:

```
<%= link_to "#{adventure.title}", adventure_path(adventure.id), class: "adventure_title", :style => 'background-image: url('+adventure.image.url(:medium)+')' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background image to a div dynamically like this:

```
 <div class="adventure" style="background: url(<%= adventure.image.url(:medium) %>) no-repeat">
      <%= link_to "#{adventure.title}", adventure_path(adventure.id), class: "adventure_title" %>
 </div>
```

and just add your css.

Answer (score -1):

Please add the change to following code.

```html
<div class="adventure_container">
  <% @adventures.each do |adventure|%>
    <div class="adventure">
      <%= link_to "#{adventure.title}", adventure_path(adventure.id), class: "adventure_title", style: "background-image: url(#{asset_path(adventure.image.url(:medium))});" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Or

```html
<div class="adventure_container">
  <% @adventures.each do |adventure|%>
    <div class="adventure">
      <%= link_to "#{adventure.title}", adventure_path(adventure.id), class: "adventure_title", style: "background-image: url(#{asset_path(adventure.image.url(:medium))});" do %>
        <%= (image_tag adventure.image.url(:medium), class:'adv_img') %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```css
// I am not a css guy. But you get the idea to adjust the background div accordingly.
.adventure {
  display: relative;
  // background-color: #e9e8e8;
  // border: 1px solid purple;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.adv_img {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1%;  
}
```